# Is there is any method in Selenium class to close the browser at the end of the Selenium Test?

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit

I am doing testing of my test cases through selenium-webdriver. I web app has some set operations like clicking,selecting etc,. i have used `selenium.click()` method. At the end of test i want to close the one popup window automatically. Is there is any method to close the popup window or browser in Selenium Class? Please help i am beginner to selenium webdriver testing. I have used selenium server 2.37.0 and the browser is IE.

Here is my code snippet:

```
namespace SeleniumTests
{                
    // this is my test method        
    [TestMethod]
    public void TheJan6Test()
    {
        selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*iexplore", "http://rcm-bpmt.apmoller.net");
        selenium.Start();
        verificationErrors = new StringBuilder();
        selenium.Open("workspace/faces/jsf/workspace/workspace.xhtml");


        // Here the steps regarding the automation of browser
        selenium.Type("id=portletComponentWorkList_viewNormalModeWorkList_viewPanel_conditionsTableSearch__OCID0__input", "198545");
        selenium.Click("id=portletComponentWorkList_viewNormalModeWorkList_viewPanel_searchWorkList");
        selenium.Click("id=portletComponentWorkList:viewNormalModeWorkList:viewPanel:instanceListTableWorkList:_OCID1_:executeLabel");

       //I want to close the popup after this step
       //At the end of test i want to close the one popup window automatically.Is there is any method to close the popup window or browser in Selenium Class
    }
}
```

Please help me how to close the pop up at the end of test.

Comment: there are tons of resources on google for you to find out there.  Have you tried searching yet?

Comment: This needs more context. A popup can be many things, such as a basic JS popup, a jQuery modal dialog, some crazy HTML5 popup, or a physical browser window. So what is it? Give us more context about the application. Also, you are using an old, deprecated (Selenium RC) version of Selenium.

Answer (score 1):

If I look at the api on http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/dotnet/html/AllMembers_T_Selenium_DefaultSelenium.htm#methodTableToggle

selenium.Close for closing popups

selenium.Stop (or Quit) for ending the current Selenium testing session (normally killing the browser)

Answer (score 1):

Probably this will help you

```
[TearDown]
public void cleanup()
{
    driver.Close();
}
```